# How do I get the Context from the Intent?

Tags: android

AccountAuthenticator.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AccountActivity.class);
```

AccountActivity.java:
In onCreate(Bundle aBundle) I want to say:

```
getIntent().getContext();
```

But getContext() does not exist.

**How do I get the Context from the Intent ?**
Since it's passed in the Intent constructor, I was expecting it to be available on arrival in the AccountActivity.

Comment: why do you need the Context from the Intent?

Comment: I need the Service (i.e. Context) that created the Intent, so as to be able to create an AsyncTask taking it in the constructor. If I don't do that I get: "java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10027 is different than the authenticator's uid", since the AsyncTask is doing Accountmanager am = Accountmanager.get(context).

Comment: For me, I was trying to use TDD and verify the correct context was being set from the code under test.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> How do I get the Context from the
>   Intent ?

You don't.

> Since it's passed in the Intent
>   constructor, I was expecting it to be
>   available on arrival in the
>   AccountActivity.

The `Context` is only used to help create the `Intent` routing information. Since an `Intent` can (and frequently does) live outside of any `Context`, an `Intent` cannot hold onto a `Context`.

> I need the Service (i.e. Context) that
>   created the Intent, so as to be able
>   to create an AsyncTask taking it in
>   the constructor.

You cannot do this, sorry.

> If I don't do that I get:
>   "java.lang.SecurityException: caller
>   uid 10027 is different than the
>   authenticator's uid", since the
>   AsyncTask is doing Accountmanager am =
>   Accountmanager.get(context).

This has nothing to do with `AsyncTask`. This has to do with processes, not threads.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Kudos :) CommonsWare